# Mongo db, querying one collection and using the result to query another

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Apologies, lots of similar questions have been answered, but I still can't resolve my issue from those. I have two collections shapes and geometry. I have successfully queried shapes to remove all red shapes

```
myquery = {"Colour": "Red"}
x = collection.delete_many(myquery)
```

But I want to use the result of this query on the geometry collection that shares the common field "Name", so that I delete any document from geometry that has a Name that was found in the original query (red shapes)

**example from shapes**

```
_id: "123"
Colour: "red"
Shape: "square"
Name: "xyz123"
Line: "bold"
```

**example from geometry**

```
 _id: "456"
Height: "6"
Width: "6"
Name: "xyz123"
Area: "36"
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know pymongo, but in mongo shell, it gonna be smth like this:

```
var namesToDelete = db.shapes.distinct("Name", { Color: "Red" });
db.geometries.deleteMany({ Name: { $in: namesToDelete }});
db.shapes.deleteMany({ Color: "Red" });
```

Disclaimer: The code is provided "as is". Please test it carefully before running on production! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution in pymongo. Basically you must get the details of the corresponding name(s) before you delete the `shapes` record because once you've deleted it, it's gone!

```
myquery = {'Colour': 'red'}
for shape in db.shapes.find(myquery):
    name = shape.get('Name')
    if name is not None:
        db.geometry.delete_many({'Name': name})

db.shapes.delete_many(myquery)
```

Comment: in this solution it will call delete_many multiple times for same Name